# Tassel vs. Tassle? Which is correctly spelled, or both?

Tags: orthography

I think I found an error in someone's work, where they spelled "tassel" as "tassle". Before I mention it to them I want to be 100% sure that this is really a problem and there is no alternate spelling.

Comment: -1 Good heavens, man! Are dictionaries forbidden to you?

Comment: @Pete, LOL, I guess this site has the potential to develop into a a http://lmgtfy.com/ for English .... and less hassle/hassel :-)

Comment: @Pete: I'm sure Mr_Crypto used a dictionary, but _tassle_ gets 5 million hits on Google and _Garner's Modern American Usage_ includes an example of it misspelled in a major newspaper. Such a common spelling confusion deserves a question on this site.

Comment: Haha, so critical....thanks for the defense Calli! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **tassel** (= a hanging ornament made of threads or strips) is sometimes misspelled *tassle*.

<sup>*Garner's Modern American Usage*</sup>

Comment: The source begs the question, is this an *American* English spelling only?